# Modifying font rendering in Firefox 69 for better looking

Tags: firefox, fonts, gdi

After update to latest Firefox 69 there is one problem with bold fonts rendering. Below is the screenshot of old browser (left, good) and new version. The problem is in bold fonts - the blue color is not so intensive in new version as should be:

[image]

I noticed, that in new version `cairo` font rendering was removed as it was in old browser:

```
gfx.canvas.azure.backends direct2d1.1,cairo,skia
gfx.content.azure.backends direct2d1.1,cairo,skia
```

Perhaps the problem is in `skia`? If in old browser I set `direct2d1.1,skia,cairo` - bold font colors becomes like in new version - bad.. Is there any solution?

Another screenshot:
[image]

Or perhaps just to switch to Firefox ESR? It has `cairo` rendering even on newest version 68.0.1.

Comment: Firefox 69.0 is currently a beta release ...

Answer (score 3):

What actually worked for me was to change `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.rendering_mode` to `5`.

You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

....After hours of searching - found a simple solution - setting at `about:config`: `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.force_gdi_classic_max_size` - just increased the default value to 100 - now all fonts up to size 100px (or infinity - not matters :) are processed by classic GDI. Backed to business :)